# The display of certain C# controls is not updating

Tags: c#, winforms, button, checkbox, controls

I have a C# winforms application which is running correctly on all but two computers. One is my own where every now and then after leaving the window and then coming back to it the controls are not showing on the screen. You can click on them and the events fire, but the area where the controls should be is blank, or looks like the previous window which was on my screen or something like that.

The second computer has this problem once in a while, but the more frequent problem is that when you click on a button you don't see the button change color and when you click on a checkbox you don't actually see the check in the box. Again, the events fire perfectly, but the user can't always tell that the button was clicked or that the checkbox was checked.

Both computers are running Windows 7 and the others are running Windows XP if that has anything to do with it.

I've been Googling forever and can't find anything. Any help is greatly appreciated. Even a decent workaround would be helpful at this point.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have a look at Multithreading.

Comment: Do you have any custom rendered controls? Or third party controls?

Comment: Clearly a refresh/redraw issue.  Someone isn't `Paint`ing the controls in a timely fashion.

Comment: Thanks everyone. At one time the code used threads but it doesn't anymore. I don't have any custom rendered or third party controls. I've tried adding repaints and refreshes and all of those in the past and never seen that it helped (this was back when it was only blanking on my screen, before I discovered this new button/checkbox issue). And, like I said, the fact that it's working on the XP computers isn't helping me find the problem. If anyone has any other suggestions, even workarounds, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The repaint seems to be the issue because the user just told me that resizing the window brings the controls back. But I can't figure out why it fails to repaint on these computers specifically, I haven't seen any specific compatibility issues mentioned with Windows 7.

Comment: In case this helps anyone, I think I've finally found the problem. I was closing another form using Form.Close() instead of Form.Dispose(). I'm still not 100% sure that this will solve every case I encountered but so far it's certainly made things much more manageable for the user.  Thanks everyone for your tips and sorry for not mentioning this other form, looking back I guess it was an important detail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I was using `Form.Close()` instead of `Form.Dispose()` on another form that was opening briefly.